# Why do these two lines not look perpendicular in Tikz/PGFPlots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This creates a simple plot with axes and the lines y = x and y = - x.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    ticks=none,
]
    \addplot[thick, black] {x};
    \addplot[thick, black] {-1 * x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Produces this (the border is an artifact of my screenshot, but its not important):
[image]

If you hold up a 90 degree angle (say a piece of paper) to the intersection of the x and y axes you can see that they are nicely perpendicular.

However, if you do the same for the lines y = x and y = -x, you see that they are *not* perpendicular.

What gives?

Comment: You aren't drawing using fixed points, but using a function, so the ratio of the _x_ and _y_ axes is important.  Try the `axis equal` option.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Sorry, didn't see your comment before I posted my answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No worries :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The axis is not square, so they shouldn't be perpendicular.

Either set the `width` and `height` to the same value in the `axis` options, or try adding `axis equal`, which will make the unit vectors in x and y have the same length.

Comment: Minor follow-up question: Do you know the rationale as to why this is the default? I would have thought that equal axes would be a natural default. This behavior is not very natural for someone coming from something like ggplot2 for example. Can you provide more information on the conceptual reason that Tikz has this behavior?

Comment: @evencoil Most data will not be suitable for an `axis equal` type plot, and apart from plain Tikz I don't know any plotting tools where it is the default. You should get a reasonable plot whether you're plotting `x` or `exp(x)`, and `axis equal` doesn’t work for that. And judging by the first example shown on the ggplot2 website, that doesn’t have axis equal as default either. (By plain TikZ I mean e.g. `\draw plot (\x, \x);` outside an `axis` environment. You're using `pgfplots` which is built on TikZ.)

Comment: Ok, I think I must be deeply confused on the underlying geometric principle then. Let me take a stab at explaining what is going on. Suppose I have a graph where both the x and y limits run from -10 to 10. If I make this graph 10cm x 10cm, then 1 unit in either the x or y direction will look like 1cm. This is what `axis equal` ensures. However, if the graph is 20cm x 10cm, then 1 unit in the x direction will look like 2cm, whereas 1 unit in the y direction will still look like 1cm. This means the way the slope of my line y = x is also going to look half as steep. Did I get it?

Comment: @evencoil Yes, that sounds about right.

Comment: Also note that the width and height options normally include space for the axis titles, etc. (even if you don't use them).